# How to Re-bind / Refresh Dom after ajax call in vuejs2 (like $scope.$apply in angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using *vue.js 2* with webpack template. i am new to vue.js.
i want to **bind DOM** **after data** is received in ajax call.
here in my code contains v-for in which the response html is need to **bind** with **v-html="tHtml[index]"** every time after data is received from api call.

What can be used to **re-bind or refresh view/DOM** as we use $scope.$apply() in angularjs.

### home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="row" id="home">
      <h3 v-if="msg"><span class="label label-warning">{{msg}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div v-for="obj in tdata">
      <div v-html="tHtml[$index]"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>
import appService from '../service'
import bus from '../service/bus'

export default {

  created() {
    appService.checkAuth();
    console.log("service appService val: "+appService.user.authenticated);
    //called after vue has been created
    bus.$on('eventBusWithTopic', (data) => {    //fetch event bus on ready to get data
      //alert("event fetched! "+data.user_id);
      console.log("event fetched! "+data.user_id);
      this.searchedTopic = data.topic;
      this.user_id = data.user_id;
      bus.$off('eventBusWithTopic');    //un-bind event after use
      //check details
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchedTopic: '',
      user_id: '',
      tdata: {},
      tHtml: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getdata(){
    console.log("dfd "+this.user_id);
      appService.getdata(this, this.user_id, this.searchedTopic).success((res) => {
          //console.log(" res: "+JSON.stringify(res));
          this.tdata = res.data;
          if(this.tdata.length > 0){ 
           //**GET HTML** // <<--==--==--==
            for(var i=0;i<this.tdata.length;i++){
              this.getTemplate(this.tdata[i].id_str);
            }
          }
          if(res.success == 0)
            this.msg = res.message;
      }).error((e) => console.log("error while getting data: "+JSON.stringify(e)))
      
    },
    getTemplate(id){
        this.$http.get("https://uqkcgyy8wb.execute-api..*****../user/"+id+"/getHtml", (resp) => {
              //return resp.data.html;
              this.tHtml[this.tHtml.length] = resp.data.html;
              console.log(this.tHtml);
          }).error((e) => console.log("error while getting html: "+JSON.stringify(e)))
          
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: You tag "vuejs2" but `ready` function is only available in vuejs 1. I think you must put you code from `ready` function to  `created` function.

Comment: `<div v-html="tHtml[$index]"></div>` where is `$index`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal index in v-for loop.

Comment: you mean here `v-for="obj in tdata"`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal yes

Comment: @DhruvGoradiya It's not here, you have explictily pass it `v-for="(obj, index) in tdata"` and you can use it as `index` and pass it down

Comment: Ok. but i am not getting any error. i am getting all proper if data from api is available before DOM binds. or tHtml[] has already html string(Static) before it binds.